# Random results from an array after loop

Tags: arrays, wordpress, loops, random, shuffle

First off, I have spent the last week plus working on putting this code together from quite a few different sources, A veritable frankenstein if you will from examples I have come across. I am not great at writing PHP but have made do thus far. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

I am working on a project in which I need to grab the latest 10 results from all Child categories of cat 4, after which I am looking to randomize the results and display.  I have seen many examples of using the **shuffle();** function, but am having issues implementing it correctly.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$categories = get_categories( 'child_of=4' );
  foreach($categories as $category) {
  $args=array(
  'showposts' => 10,
  'category__in' => array($category->term_id),
  'caller_get_posts'=>1
);
$posts=get_posts($args);
  shuffle($posts);
  if ($posts) {
    foreach($posts as $post) {
      setup_postdata($post); ?>
        <div <?php post_class('boxy');?>>
      <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php  the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>

    <?php the_content(''); ?>
    </div>
      <?php
    } 
  } 
} 
?>
```

link to my results here:[Live work in progress](http://stephenperrett.net/Crave-new/?page_id=14)

This code is randomizing results in each category, but displaying them by category..
I hope i have been clear enough for what seems like a simple fix.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make array of all post first with all categories you have. Than you need to shuffle the same. Try this,

```
 $posts = array();
 $categories = get_categories( 'child_of=4' );
 foreach($categories as $category) {
   $args=array(
    'showposts' => 10,
    'category__in' => array($category->term_id),
    'caller_get_posts'=>1
   );
 $posts = $posts + get_posts($args);
} // Close your foreach here
```

....than your code as it is...

Comment: Worked like a charm, just had to change the number of 'showposts' to a higher number as is was displaying only 10 results total

Comment: Hmm, I added a new child cat that should display with this code ad am having trouble getting it to display.  I cut out the child of and was able to display them via cat id for the post type specifically, but after trying i still cannot figure why the new cat wont display along with the others..

Answer (score 0):

```
$categories = get_categories( 'child_of=4' );
$cats = array();
foreach($categories as $category) {
   $cats[] = $category->term_id;
}

$args=array(
  'showposts' => 10,
  'category__in' => $cats,
  'orderby' => 'rand',
  'caller_get_posts'=>1
);
$posts=get_posts($args);
```

I hope this will be a more effective solution. I haven't tested it out.